# Visual Studio Code Java Plugin not resolving Gradle implementations and Java imports

Tags: java, android, visual-studio-code, gradle, vscode-extensions

Ok, so i'm very new to Gradle and Native Android development (i've worked with Flutter a little bit). I've installed the Microsoft Java plugin, as well as the Gradle plugin for VSCode, followed the Google's Android dev reference, and tried to setup a development environment. Everything went fine, except for this. The Gradle implementations that i use (in this example, androidx.appcompat) don't get "recognized" by VSCode. I runned a `gradle build` to get the dependencies and they show correctly in the Gradle window. But the Java plugin can't resolve the import, like this:

[Gradle Dependency Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKOYf.png)

[Java Projects Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ry4F4.png)

I've searched all day for an answer. The only thing i saw was a solution to a similar problem, solved by cleaning the java workspace from the command pallet. This did not work for me.

Comment: Try adding `apply plugin: 'java-library'` to the *build.gradle* file.